# Instrument rating foreign pilot via non-basa(IFP) or foreign pilot via basa( IFB)?

Tags: faa-regulations, instrument-rating

I'm a peruvian comercial pilot trying to get the FAA private license and also the instrument rating. My question as the tittle says; I'm confuse about which one I'm supposed to take.I've been looking at the FAR and also googleing but there is no solid answer about that. I know is related to the Bilateral Aviation Safety Agreement (BASA) and the countries involved. However I cannot find if my country is part of it(I'm from Peru). Could anyone know where can I find it or have the link so I could give it a look. Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "foreing"?  Also, what is IFP and IFB?  I can sort of get what you are asking in the body, but the title is very confusing.

Comment: I meant foreign, this is what I have from FAA airman knowledge testing:
NOTE: Effective 9/5/22, the new Instrument Rating Foreign Pilot via BASA (61.71) (IFB) test is available for administration; and the
Instrument Rating Airplane Foreign Pilot (IFP) test has changed, in name only, to Instrument Rating Foreign Pilot via Non-BASA (61.75).

Comment: And my question is about this, the fact that I don't know which of the test I'm supposed to take because BASA supposed to be between the countries that have the agreement( I cant find a list of the countries that are part of it). And depending on that, the number of question will be different.